# Access JIRA with VBA Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, jira, jira-rest-api

I want to automate Excel reports in JIRA using VBA and Excel, I am trying to access JIRA with VBA to export data to Excel. So, I start with the authentification and then try to export data using this code :

```
Private JiraService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Private JiraAuth As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Sub JIRA()

  With JiraAuth
       .Open "POST", "https://jiralink/rest/auth/1/session", False
       .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
       .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
       .send " {""username"" : """username""", ""password"" : """password"""}"""
       MsgBox .Status
       If .Status = "200" Then
           sCookie = "JSESSIONID=" & Mid(sErg, 42, 32) & "; Path=/" & sPfad
           Login = True
       End If
  End With

  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://jiralink/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-all-fields/temp/SearchRequest.html?jqlQuery=project+%3D+NAME+AND+Sprint+%3D+1+ORDER+BY+priority+DESC%2C+updated+DESC&tempMax=1000" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

I've get ERROR : 403 forbidden
Can anyone help me please ? 
Sorry, i am new to VBA and JIRA

Comment: are you entering the proper username and password in the `send` request? Also just because you have logged into JIRA through webservice does not mean the query connection has proper login credentials supplied.

Comment: Thank for your replay @Scott Holtzman, yes, the username and password are correct

Comment: I want to connect to my JIRA account and then access the url <https://jiralink/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-all-fields/temp/SearchRequest.html?jqlQuery=project+%3D+NAME+AND+Sprint+%3D+1+ORDER+BY+priority+DESC%2C+updated+DESC&tempMax=1000> that allows me to export data to Excel

Answer (score 0):

I used this to extract information from our Jira server, I am using JsonConverter from https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON to get data converted from Json:

```
'Option Explicit
Dim jiraURL, Auth, restReq
Dim Url, responseCode, responseContent
Sub startFunction()
Dim loginOk As Boolean

loginOk = PrepareLogin

If (loginOk = True) Then
    getIssues 'Login ok, now fetch all issues
End If
MsgBox "All done"
End Sub
Sub getIssues()
Dim wsStartPage As Worksheet
Dim jsonResp As Object
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim issueName As String
Dim i As Long
Dim moreJiratoRead As Boolean
Dim jiraPosition As Long
    
currentRow = 1

Set wsStartPage = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MyIssues")
wsStartPage.Cells(currentRow, 1) = "Issue Name"
currentRow = currentRow + 1
moreJiratoRead = True
jiraPosition = 0
    
Do While (moreJiratoRead = True)

    Url = jiraURL & "rest/api/latest/search?jql=project in (someProjectNames) and status not in (dismissed, done, closed, resolved)&startAt=" & CStr(jiraPosition) & "&maxResults=1000&expand=fields&fields=key,status"
    restReq.Open "GET", Url, False
    restReq.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Auth
    restReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    restReq.Send
    responseCode = restReq.Status
    responseContent = restReq.responseText
    Set jsonResp = JsonConverter.ParseJson(responseContent)
    Set issues = jsonResp("issues")

    If issues.Count = 1000 Then 'This will allow me to read all issues without limitation
        jiraPosition = jiraPosition + 1000
    Else
        moreJiratoRead = False
    End If

    
    i = 1
    Do While i <= issues.Count
        issueName = CStr(issues(i)("key"))
        wsStartPage.Cells(currentRow, 1) = issueName
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
        i = i + 1
    Loop
Loop
End Sub

Function PrepareLogin() As Boolean
Dim uid, pwd

PrepareLogin = False
uid = InputBox("Please enter your windows login id", "Windows Login")
If Len(Trim(uid)) = 0 Then
    Exit Function
Else
    pwd = InputBox("Please enter your windows password", "Windows Password")
    If Len(Trim(pwd)) = 0 Then
        Exit Function
    End If
End If

PrepareLogin = init(uid, pwd)

End Function

Function init(JIRA_USER, JIRA_PWD) As Boolean
'Login and get session ID.
Dim sOutput
Dim sCookie

init = True
jiraURL = "https://someURL/"
Set restReq = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
restReq.setTimeouts 6000000, 6000000, 6000000, 6000000

restReq.Open "POST", jiraURL & "/rest/auth/1/session", False
restReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
restReq.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
restReq.Send " {""username"" : """ & JIRA_USER & """, ""password"" : """ & JIRA_PWD & """}"
sOutput = restReq.responseText

If (InStr(1, LCase(sOutput), LCase("login failed")) Or InStr(1, LCase(sOutput), LCase("unauthorized"))) > 0 Then
    init = False
    MsgBox sOutput
    End
End If
sCookie = "JSESSIONID=" & Mid(sOutput, 42, 32) & "; Path=/Jira"

End Function
```

Comment: You need to replace someProjectNames with some project names in Jira and you need to replace someURL with your Jira Server, i.e. jira.company.com and you need to install the JsonConverter that I mention to convert the feedback you get from the Jira API.